# Is it possible to add a search function in a gmail add on app?

Tags: gmail, add-on, gmail-addons

So we're trying to build a gmail add-on where users can just search and create food orders via email. So I'm wondering is it possible to add a search function and fetch list of restaurants from our site and display them in the add-on.

Comment: sure it is  - you just need to create/program them.. Have a look at gmail labs experimental features or do it via chrome-extensions ;)

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   Please edit your question and include any research you have done into your issue.  Any code you have and describe the issue you are having with your solution.    As it is currently written your question is to broad for us to be able to assist you.

Comment: If your site provides an API to do that , it is possible.